# Amazon DynamoDB - Joins

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a question regarding joins in Amazon Dynamo DB. As Amazon Dynamo DB is a NoSQL database and doesn't supports joins. I am looking for an alternate solution for using a join command for Dynamo DB tables. I am using Dynamo DB with Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

**No way to do joins in Dynamo DB.**

- Dynamo db table's primary key is a composite of partition key & sort
  key. You must need partition key to query in table.
- It is not like Relational Database, Dynamo DB table is irrespective
  of data type. SO it's quite complicate to use joins in it.

> Query each table individually & use values of resultant to proceed with other table.

Answer (score 1):

Since DynamoDB is a NOSQL Database It doesn't support RDBMS. So you cannot join tables in the dynamo db. AWS has other databases which support RDBMS like **AWS Aurora**.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work at Rockset- but I def. see that this can help you solve this issue really easily. Yes, you can't do joins on DynamoDB, but you can indirectly do joins using Dyanmodb integrated with Rockset.

1. Create integration between dynamo db giving Rockset read permissions.
2. Write your SQL query with JOIN on the editor
3. Save the SQL query as a RESTFUL endpoint via Query Lambda on Rockset console.
4. On your android app, making a HTTP request to that endpoint and get your query:

Assuming you imported all the proper libraries:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String url = "https://api.rs2.usw2.rockset.com/v1/orgs/self/ws/commons/lambdas/LambdaName/versions/versionNumber";
    private String APIKEY = "ApiKey YOUR APIKEY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("url");
    }

    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpPost.addHeader("Authorization" , APIKEY);
                httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type" , "application/json");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    Log.e("foo", data);

                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);

                    return true;
                } else {
                    Log.e("foo", "error" + String.valueOf(status));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        }
    }
}
```

From there, you'll get your results as a log and then you can do what you want with that data.

While you can't do JOINS directly on DyanmoDB, you can indirectly with Rockset if you're building data-driven applications.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDb is a NoSQl database and as such you cant do joins.
However from my experience there isn't anything you can't do if you create a correct design of your database.Use a single table and a combination of primary and secondary keys.
Here are the  docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use joins in DynamoDB, but you can structure your data in a single table using GSI indexes, so that you can query data in most of the possible way.

So before designing database structure, you will need to make a list of all the queries that will need and design DB structure, mainly set indexes, according to that.